# I'm time-travelling aka there seems to be something wrong with the caching

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page

I've noticed recently that, when viewing the comments tab, my user-page decides to go back to an arbitrary point in time. It's also getting earlier and earlier.

This seems to be my user-page as of a month ago. This screenshot was captured, this morning, from a newly opened page (i.e. one that hadn't been sat on my browser for a month).

[image: old]

And the current one (also newly opened this morning)

[image: new]

This also happened earlier in the week but it only went back a few weeks rather than an entire month.

I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.52 and have deleted cookies and emptied the cache after the last time this occurred.

I'm not really certain how to explain this but it seems like SO is displaying my user-page as it would have appeared a month ago. It doesn't happen often and, so far, has only occurred when on the comments tab.

I, perhaps wrongly, assumed that a cached version of the page was being displayed.

It may well be [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro); it's not that important just a little disconcerting.

Comment: Similar to [Activity overview not displaying today's reputation correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125694/activity-overview-not-displaying-todays-reputation-correctly)

Comment: @Tim, thanks for that. Couldn't find a duplicate at all. That seems to have been a one-off though whereas this has been persistent.

Comment: And now your rep has gone all the way down to 1024! Oh wait, that's your meta rep.

Comment: @Ben: Lock your account! You now have a perfect round number on MSO!

Comment: @Tim :-). By the time I read that I no longer did. Maybe you better down-vote to try and get it back?

Comment: @Ben: can't unupvote till you edit the post :P

Comment: What comments-tab?

Comment: @garden http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136489/garden-gnobobby?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: Oh that one...if I see this correctly, this is only some async-loading...so it's very odd that your userpage changes with it.

Comment: Until you answer questions before they are asked (see my comments to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61303/147655), you won't be a real time traveler :)

Comment: I cannot parse this: "as of a month ago (opened this morning)", explain? I'm not seeing the issue here...

Comment: @Nick, I've tried to clarify the question. Basically I'm occasionally seeing an old profile page; or a profile page with old data on it.

Comment: @Ben - are you behind a proxy at a workplace? There's no way you'd get an ancient page like that from our servers, it's just not technically possible for that to happen.

Comment: @Nick, no this has only happened at home (no proxy / nothing special).

Comment: @Ben - are you behind a proxy at home? You have a cache layer somewhere, whether it be local or at a proxy server level, but you're seeing cached content delivered...and not from us.

Comment: @Nick, sorry, just updated the previous comment. My ISP might have a cache-layer but at home I've got nothing but the browser.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I've been getting this for months on all the SE sites I use. It was a shock when it first happened to see all that rep go away, but now it's just irritating as I use the Activity tab to review what I've done. Interestingly we're both in London, we both use Chrome, and we're both seeing the issue running from home. It looks like it's probably Chrome caching rather than an ISP issue, however.