# Pressing browser's back button takes you to a few days ago's homepage

Tags: bug, new-nav, back-button

I've been noticing this for quite a while, but I've now tested on OSX Yosemite and Windows 10 Chrome, both latest versions, and in incognito mode. I shut down the computer every day.

Steps to repro:

- have [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav)
- go to the homepage of Meta
- click a question
- use your browser's back button to go back
- you'll see the homepage that shows events as if you traveled back in time

Demonstration gif:

> [image]

You can see the top question is completely different when I go back.

Right after it happened, I opened `chrome://view-http-cache/http://meta.stackexchange.com/` (before refreshing the page) and saw a recent timestamp.

Why is this? Can it be fixed? Please?

Comment: MSO duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302479/stale-cache-issue-question-from-almost-14-days-ago-appears-in-recent-stream

Comment: I repro this on-and-off, it doesn't have a stable repro scenario as far as I can tell, but it does and did happen for me the last couple of days several times.

Comment: +1 I have noticed this when I was using 'new-nav'. I was going to report this but then back off as someone may say 'blame cache'. Which is semi-true as I can refresh the page and loads the post correctly. I opt out from the new-nav few days ago but because of the [Where did my question go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261937/where-did-my-newly-posted-question-go) issue which has now fixed aka [status-completed]

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134748/179419

Comment: @Ben, your duplicate is 3 years old...?

Comment: It doesn't mean that Chrome's caching problem had gone away @Arjan.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I think this is different purely because it **only happens on new nav**...

Comment: This happened to me too. Decided to not make a question because I couldn't figure how to make a GIF :(

Comment: @PythonMaster LiceCap - http://licecap.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Still 100% reproducible for me. It's really annoying

Comment: @ClausJørgensen yep, still is, but I don't find as annying now - I've trained myself to just click the site logo whenever I want to go back now! :P