# I'm Going Back Through Time

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, new-nav

For some reason, the new-nav is going crazy. It sets my rep back like by 200 rep, and thinks the most recent comment wasn't viewed. I know this sounds crazy, but it is the truth. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

This is not a fake because you can still see the tab where I am writing this question. But everything else is not correct. At the time of writing this post, we are at 71.3k questions, not 71.2k. senshin did not have the newest question right now, I did not have any notifications while writing, nor do I have 3,643 right now (I actually have 3,832 rep).

So is this a late April Fools/Welcome back to School joke or is this a major time bug? If yes to major time bug, please tell me what is going on. Using Google Chrome. Oh, everything is normal after refresh. This happened to me about 3 times today.

**EDIT:** Here it comes again...

[image]

Comment: what happens when you do hard refresh or click on the 'new' again?

Comment: You're off by 1 - I see you have 3832

Comment: @James, I think he means that ***one*** of my info is incorrect. I had 3.832 rep at asking not 3.843

Comment: related stale caching issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263706/pressing-browsers-back-button-takes-you-to-a-few-days-agos-homepage